# how do i connect to Microsoft sql server 2008 in python

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, database, ubuntu

I want to connect to Microsoft sqlserver 2008 in python, I am using ubuntu and mysql server 2008 is at remote location running on port 1433, this mysql server is installed on microsoft server 2008, this is virtualized os which is running on vmware workstation further this vmware is installed on windows 7.

Comment: Is it MySQL or MS SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Microsoft sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

install http://www.pymssql.org/ from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.0

Example use here:

http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/_mssql_examples.html

and here

http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html

Very simple.